# Display Image with Backbone + KineticJS

Tags: backbone.js, image-processing, kineticjs

I'm trying to load an image on canvas using Backbone + KineticJS. However the image doesn't seem to appear.

First I load the images using a model. (I'm loading the image locally so its already available)

```
var KineticModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    myImg: null,
    createImg : function() {
            var imageObj = new Image();
            var kinImg = new Kinetic.Image()

            imageObj.onload = function() {
                kinImg.setAttrs({
                    x: 10,
                    y: 10,
                    image: imageObj, 
                    width: 578,
                    height: 400
                })
            }
            imageObj.src = 'test/img/vader.png';
            return kinImg;
        }
    });
```

Then create the View

```
var KineticView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: 'container',
    stage: null,
    layer: null,

    initialize: function (options) {
        model: options.model;
        el: options.el;
        this.layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        this.stage = new Kinetic.Stage({ container: this.el, width: 600, height: 600 });
        this.stage.add(this.layer);
    },
    render: function () {
        var myImg = this.model.createImg();
        this.layer.add(myImg);
        this.stage.add(this.layer);
        this.stage.draw();

    }
    });
```

Finally to tie it all up

```
var KModel= new KineticModel({});
    var imgcontainer = $('#container').get();
    view = new KineticView({model:KModel, el:imgcontainer});
    view.render();
```

The page loads without any errors, but no image.
Console logs show that the Image Models have been passed to the layers.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redraw layer after setting attrs:

```
kinImg.setAttrs({
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    image: imageObj, 
    width: 578,
    height: 400
});
yourLayer.draw();
```

**Note:** you are working with view (Kinetic object) inside `Backbone.Model` - this is bad approach. Model should works only with data. Move `createImg` function to View.

Also look at this plugin: https://github.com/slash-system/backbone.kineticview

Comment: Thanks! I missed out redrawing layers. I actually used KineticView before this but the same problem surfaced. Will try out your suggestion!